# Angle between a plane defined by three points (x, y, z are unknown) and the horizontal

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image: The image is taken from wikipedia]

I am a novice in mathematics, and I have a question:

Suppose that I have 3 points in the space:

- (x,y,z) for these points are not known for me.
- given that I know the angles a, b and c (c.f. above image); for each of the three vectors connecting each two points, with respect to the horizontal plane (and also the distance between each two points), is it possible to calculate the angle between the plane defined by these points and the horizontal plane?

Thank you in advance for any response.

Comment: When you say three points you mean you have 3 points $P_1=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$,$P_2=(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ and $P_3=(x_3,y_3,z_3)$ and horizontal plane meaning the x-y plane?

Comment: @GTX OC, I mean a point in the space but their x, y and z coordinates are unknown for me.

Comment: But you know the angle that the vector makes with the 3 axis right?

Comment: I know the angles that each vector, connecting each two points, makes with the 3 axes (without its position).

Comment: Do you know about direction ratios and direction cosines?

Comment: It is possible to calculate these values since I know the a, b and c for each vector in addition to its magnitude, but how can I afterward calculate the angle between the defined plane and the horizontal one (xy plane)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I can make out:

Suppose I take 3 points $P_1$,$P_2$ and $P_3$. Hence the direction cosines(according to the question) are known. Let me assume the direction cosines as follows
$$P_1P_2 \equiv <p_1,q_1,r_1>$$
$$P_2P_3 \equiv <p_2,q_2,r_2>$$
$$P_3P_1 \equiv <p_3,q_3,r_3>$$
We know that direction cosines is the direction ratios of a unit vector. Since the lengths of the given vectors are given(assuming them to be $l_1,l_2,l_3$),if we multiply $l_1$ with the d.c.s of $P_1P_2$ we get the direction ratios of of $P_1P_2$. Similarly we can get the direction ratios of the the other 2 vectors.

The direction ratio of the x-y plane is $$(0,0,1)$$ We can find the direction ratio os the normal of the plane containing the three points by taking the cross product of any of the two vectors(say $\overrightarrow {P_1P_2}$ and $\overrightarrow {P_2P_3 }$). Finally taking the dot product of the direction ratio of normal with that of x-y plane will give you the desired angle)

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I will think about that and try it on Matlab supposing three known points and I will come back to confirm.

Comment: I hope I didn't go overboard with taking cross and dot products. If you know the outcomes of taking dot and cross products the logic is very simple.

Comment: The answer is correct except that the desired angle will be given by:
angle = atan2(norm(cross(n_p1p2p3,[0,0,1])),dot(n_p1p2p3,[0,0,1]));
where n_p1p2p3 is the normal on the plane p1p2p3.

Thank you so much for your answer.